# UIView.init() must be used from main thread only (when i segue to this controller)

Tags: ios, swift

Hello this is my controller class

```
 class  passwordViewController: UIViewController {

 let load = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .whiteLarge) // cause error

 let passwordTextFiled:UITextField = { // cause error

            let pass = UITextField()
            pass.placeholder = ""
            pass.addDoneButtonOnKeyboard()
            pass.textColor = .gray
            pass.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
            return pass
        }()

        let barLabel:UILabel = {
            let bar = UILabel()
            bar.text=""
            bar.backgroundColor = Colors.yellow
            return bar
        }()
         // there is more code here.i avoid to copy
}
```

when i run this controller directly it is okay no error. but when i segue from other controller here cause this error

UIView.init() must be used from main thread only

update 1 :

there is A controller  with one button and the button segue to controller B

and this is my segue code :

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async {

            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "passVC", sender: nil)

           }
```

and i have B controller's code here
swift 4 and code 10

Comment: Add code from previous controller where you call segue

Comment: Hello Ryan. This code does not show the underlying problem, but it makes me assume you're relatively new to iOS development? It is unusual to declare your UI elements using closures like this, usually you work with a storyboard or at least a xib file. Anyway, the error indicates that somehow you initialize a view not from the main thread. According to what you write that somehow happens during a segue transition, but without seeing how you do this we cannot provide help.

Comment: Can you show how you are using segue?

Comment: update my post.

Comment: You are using a segue, which means you are using a storyboard, so why are you creating UI elements programmatically? Use `@IBOutlet`s and create them I the storyboard.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The error is telling you that you are creating the view controller from a background thread and that it must be created on the main thread (All UI work must be done on the main thread).

So when you are in the background thread and want to do UI work, you should use a dispatch queue call to run the code in the correct thread.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   // UI work here
}
```

So in your case, I imagine you are doing some network request to check authentication.

```
networkService.checkAuth() { auth in 
     // do whatever NON UI work you need to here
     DispatchQueue.main.async {
         // UI work here
     }
}
```

Comment: in swift 4 the compiler shows the line of error in updating ui view out of main thread. see my first post again i have comment it the line causes the problem.thanks for your edition

Answer (score 2):

```
  DispatchQueue.main.async { 
       //do UIWork here 
}
```